# Change text input value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, input

So i have something like 10 or more `<input type=text>` in which i fill them with database values by using php.

Some of the values will be `0` so the inputs will get their `value` set to 0. I want to select all those inputs and set their value to empty as the window loads.

I've did some googling but did not find any script that would help me do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('input[type="text"][value="0"]').val('');
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/WPrNU/

Comment: @DaftDev Great! it is simple indeed!

Answer (score 5):

Try this,

```
$(function(){
    $('input[type=text]').each(function(){
       if($(this).val()==0)
       {
           $(this).val('');
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using PHP to populate the values:

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" value=\"".($the_value ?: "")."\" />";
```

This will convert any falsy values (in particular `0`) to the empty string.

Comment: Ah, but with that "better answer" the value will show as 0, and then suddenly disappear. That's very bad design.

Comment: That can occur, i agree but there is a better answer because your way i would have to change all inputs and many of the have diferent class, etc. More work would be needed and the "better answer" works fine for me.

Comment: So basically what you're saying is you're lazy and can't be bothered to do a simple Find+Replace to make your site just a little better?

Comment: no, i'm saying it works for me because all of the inputs i have are hidden and will only show up after an user event. So that gives more then enough time to run the script to set their value from 0 to empty. It's more simple and it wouldnt require any find+replace

Comment: Hmm... -narrows eyes- I guess that'll do, but still... if there's any error in the JavaScript it will show zeroes bright as day.

Answer (score 3):

You have mentioned.

> in which i fill them with database values by using php

The **PHP** code

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['your_column']==0){ $row['your_column']=''; };
    }
```

Comment: @DaftDev, Mine is safe and best , the other answers may not work 100% because, if you replace `input type="text"` with `input type=" text"` , all of the above code will fail.

Comment: No worries, why would i replace `input type="text"` with `input type=" text"`

Comment: @DaftDev, I didn't mean intentionally you do, what if you did accidentally ?

Comment: @DaftDev. Oh yea. you will. Peace !